# Migration of Public Folders to Shared Mailboxes with a script?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, public-folders

My customer is currently migrating to another Exchange environment. Company policy says no public folders are allowed in the new environment. My customer has over a TB of public folder data, which needs to be preserved.

The public folders should be migrated to shared mailboxes.

I'm looking for a way to automate this (I know my way in C# and Powershell) but I haven't been able to find code examples or other solutions. I've looked at [Ontrack](http://www.krollontrack.com/software/powercontrols/) but I do not think they have a solution to this particular case.

Can anyone provide some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend our *ReliefJet Essentials Professional Edition* for this. It provides command line that will surely suite your needs. There is an example of [exporting Public Folders to PST files](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookItemsExportPST). You can use [Copy or Move Outlook Items](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookItemsCopy) the similar way to copy your Public Folders to Shared Mailboxes using batch script(s).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of limits placed upon shared mailboxes in newer targets such as Office365, including mailbox size, concurrent connections, etc. If you have a large public folder estate, you may need to split the public folders across multiple shared mailboxes and a simple script to shift the data across might not be adequate. There are 3ed party tools available that automate this process including [Ultimate Migrator](http://ultimatemigrator.com)